# Download from FTP with Python - Pathname

Tags: python, ftp

I'm using the ftplib to connect to my FTP-server.

I want to download a file from my FTP-server to a specified directory on my computer.
I have this simple code:

```
def download(ftp,file):
    f = open(file,"wb")
    ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + file,f.write)
    f.close()
```

What do I have to add to this code to download the file to my requested directory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the call to `open` with the local path you want to write to.  For example:

```
import os
def download(ftp,file, localdir):
    f = open(os.path.join(localdir, file),"wb")
    ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + file,f.write)
    f.close()
```